# Like and Sorting Operation in Grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I want sort grid view data using like operator as like SQL Query

```
SELECT     Acc_Name, Opening_bal
FROM         Acc_Sub_SubHead
WHERE     (Acc_Name LIKE N'%sa%')
ORDER BY CHARINDEX('s', Acc_Name)
```

i have tried this way

```
DataTable table = this.GVProductList.DataSource as DataTable;
table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%' ";
```

Comment: Have your tried the `ASC` or `DESC` on your query?

Comment: @Andrei No, Not yet.

Comment: **1.** How did you set the DataSource of DataGridView?  **2.** What are the column names and types which you want to sort and filter?  **3.** What's the error message or unexpected behavior that you see?

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 solutions for you 1 one is using DataTable.

```
    void loadGrid()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] {
                new DataColumn("Acc_Name", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Opening_bal",typeof(decimal)) });
        dt.Rows.Add("Alpasce", "20");
        dt.Rows.Add("Cvcpas", "1000");
        dt.Rows.Add("Jpasmal", "500");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
     
    }
    void searchAndOrderGrid()
    {
        DataTable table = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

        var results = (from myRow in table.AsEnumerable()
                       where myRow.Field<string>("Acc_Name").Contains("as")
                       orderby myRow.Field<string>("Acc_Name").IndexOf("s")
                       select myRow).ToList();

        DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();
        dtNew.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] {
                new DataColumn("Acc_Name", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Opening_bal",typeof(decimal)) });
        if (results != null)
        {
            foreach (var row in results)
            {
                dtNew.Rows.Add(row.Field<string>("Acc_Name"), row.Field<decimal>("Opening_bal"));
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtNew;
            
        }
    }
```

**Note:** This is not optimized. You can optimize it or you can do it more efficient way.
***2nd Solution is using Class Object***

```
public class Acc_Sub_SubHead
{
    public string Acc_Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Opening_bal { get; set; }
}
void loadData()
{
        List<Acc_Sub_SubHead> Items = new List<Acc_Sub_SubHead>();
        Items.Add(new Acc_Sub_SubHead() { Acc_Name = "Alpasce", Opening_bal = 202 });
        Items.Add(new Acc_Sub_SubHead() { Acc_Name = "Cvcpas", Opening_bal = 365 });
        Items.Add(new Acc_Sub_SubHead() { Acc_Name = "Jpasmal", Opening_bal = 125 });

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Items;
 }
 void searchAndOrderby()
 {
        List<Acc_Sub_SubHead> tempItems = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as List<Acc_Sub_SubHead>;
        var orderedData = tempItems.Where(c => c.Acc_Name.Contains("as")).OrderBy(x => x.Acc_Name.IndexOf("s")).ToList();
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = orderedData;
        
 }
```

**Note:** I like the second way. It is more efficient and faster than the first one. I have tested both codes and it works. Please check and let me know.

Comment: Downvote for `dataGridView1.Refresh();` You don't need to call this method in this context. Please read the documentation.

Comment: It was just for display purpose. UI was not updating while I was using this code. Did you check my code? If you don't check the code, then why did you gave me a unnecessary vote.

Comment: Fix the code and I'll remove the downvote